# Quaternion derivative proof

Tags: rotations, quaternions

In [this](https://www.euclideanspace.com/physics/kinematics/angularvelocity/QuaternionDifferentiation2.pdf) paper I tried to understand the Quaternion derivative formula derivation for a body angular rates but I got lost right after equation 12 it states that p(t) is a vector since it's scalar part is 0. where did that come from ?
I don't get it why the product of each quaternion part with it's derivative sums up to zero, can someone elaborate that for me, thanks

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Hint: differentiate $q_0^2+q_1^2+q_2^2+q_3^2=1\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. 
OH, good hint I got it thanks, but also how does this relate to it being it's scalar part I mean why q1, q2 and q3 terms are also there ?
shouldn't it be q0 only ?

Comment: "its" scalar part is the one of $p$ not of $q.$

Comment: @KurtG. 
ah It's the result of the multiplication done in prev step got it thanks a lot

Comment: @KurtG. you can add the answer for it for future visitors I will accept

Comment: Since you have not addressed Jose Carlos Santos' comment your post is still low quality and should be closed. Even with MathJax the question is too simple. I am voting to close.